# Reload Javascript when redirected to other page with turbolink in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I display the table page only when the page is completely loaded. There are two such pages in the application. To achieve this I set the 'style="display:none"' for the table in the corresponding view and when the page is completely loaded I show the table through the Javascript file using '$('mytable').show()'. The first page has link to other similar page which should display table, but when I click the link the table on other page remains hidden. I know this happens because the Javascript (which unhides the table)is not executed again. How do share the Javascript between those two pages? Note I have other Javascript code as well which I want to share between these two pages.

**Known solution:**
Removing 'turbolinks' does the trick for me, but then every time I switch between pages the loading is quite slow. Is there way to make this work so that the performance is not impacted.

My Javascript is located at 'app/assets/javascripts/myscript.js'.

I have a single controller 'mycontroller' and two actions, 'index' with view 'view1' and 'index1' with view 'view2'. Both the views display similar tables with different data.

I tried searching over internet but could not find a relevant post.

Please let me know if I need to share any more details.

Thank you for the help!

**Solution:** I found the solution on Rails Guide, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Directly from the [Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks):

> **5.2 Page Change Events** When writing CoffeeScript, you'll often want to do some sort of processing upon page load. With jQuery, you'd write
>   something like this:
>
> `$(document).ready ->   alert "page has loaded!"` However, because
>   Turbolinks overrides the normal page loading process, the event that
>   this relies on will not be fired. If you have code that looks like
>   this, you must change your code to do this instead:
>
> `$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->   alert "page has loaded!"` For
>   more details, including other events you can bind to, check out the
>   Turbolinks README.

Just modify that sample to reload the table, instead of an alert.

Comment: Thanks @UlyssesInvictus. Can this be done using pure Javascript or jQuery? All of the files are written in Javascript and I do not want to mix coffeescript with it.

Comment: Yeah, Coffescript is just syntatic sugar for JS. Try `$(document).on("ready", function)` or `$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function)`

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to work, additionally this time the code under the 'function' does not execute even if the page is reloaded. I tried '$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function)' this one.

Comment: '$(document).on("page:change", function)' seems to work.

Comment: My bad `turbolinks:load` is Rails 5. You can also use `page:load` to get this behavior.

Comment: I'm using Rails 5 and the `turbolinks:load` fix saved me. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this on the bottom of the second page

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(main);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read section 5.2 at [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks), that worked for me:

> > When writing CoffeeScript, you'll often want to do some sort of processing upon page load. With jQuery, you'd write something like this:
> >
> > $(document).ready ->
> >       alert "page has loaded!"
> >
> > However, because Turbolinks overrides the normal page loading process, the event that this relies on will not be fired. If you have code that looks like this, you must change your code to do this instead:
> >
> > $(document).on "page:change", ->
> >       alert "page has loaded!"